# Flutter how to load Future list in a ListView?

Tags: list, flutter

Hi how i can Load this list in a ListView or ListViebuilder?

```
 Future<List<bool>> getBoolList() async{
  List<bool> prefList = [];
  var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Set<String> keys = sharedPreferences.getKeys();

  for(int i=0; i<keys.length ; i++){
    bool value = sharedPreferences.getBool(keys.elementAt(i));
    prefList.add(value);
  }
  
  return prefList;
}

List<bool> list = await getBoolList();
```

how I got there
[Flutter SharedPreferences how to load all saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542664/flutter-sharedpreferences-how-to-load-all-saved)

Edit: my favorite.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class Favoriten extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoritenState createState() => _FavoritenState();
}

class _FavoritenState extends State<Favoriten> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Favorites'),
      ),
      body: // MyList
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the error message that you get ?

Comment: i have no errors i don't know how to display the bools as a list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use stream builder. It observes the stream. (Best way to implement is using bloc pattern)

```
class Favoriten extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoritenState createState() => _FavoritenState();
}

class _FavoritenState extends State<Favoriten> {

  final _boolList = PublishSubject<List<bool>>();
  Observable<List<bool>> get boolList => _boolList.stream;

  loadList() async{
    List<bool> prefList = [];
    var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Set<String> keys = sharedPreferences.getKeys();

    for(int i=0; i<keys.length ; i++){
      bool value = sharedPreferences.getBool(keys.elementAt(i));
      prefList.add(value);
    }

    _boolList.sink.add(prefList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadList();
    return StreamBuilder(
          stream: boolList,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return root(snapshot.data);
            } else {
              return Container(
                child: YourLoader(),// display loader
              );
            }
          }
      );
  }

  Widget root(List<bool> list){
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         return Container(); // your design here
      }
      itemCount: list.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Note :- You have to add rxdart: ^0.22.0 plugin in your pubspec.yaml
and then import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

Comment: I have a lot of mistakes when I insert this :( how do i add this to my page? I added my page to my question

Comment: can you still help me?

Comment: @Marcel you need to cover some basics before you jump into all this. I will recommend you to go through some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently studying, but can you still help me with the problem?

Comment: Add the code above in your _FavoritenState class. Wrap StreamBuilder inside Scaffold.

Comment: The method 'PublishSubject' isn't defined ---- Undefined class 'Observable' ---- Providing a non-null itemCount improves the ability of the [ListView]----- The method 'YourLoader' isn't defined for the type '_FavoritenState' have thi errors

Comment: why don't you help me to the end? there is not much left to do

Comment: rxdart: ^0.22.0, use this plugin. This will remove - 'PublishSubject' isn't defined, Undefined class 'Observable'. I wrote 'YourLoader' for you to show the progress bar which you are using for your project

Comment: dont understand what you mean with Observable can you show me the complete code with my favorite.dart?

Comment: i see you have edit your post but i still have mistakes on Observable (Undefined class 'Observable') on YourLoader (The method 'YourLoader' isn't defined for the type '_FavoritenState'.) and on itemCount (Expected to find ','.)

Comment: and that is missing scatfold in your example

Comment: can someone help me?

Comment: Hey @Arpit Awasthi can you still help me?